# To get the total working hours in sql server using procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008

Sir My Procedure is

```
USE [PGATE_GITS]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[usp_GetTimeReport_Weekly1]    Script Date: 03/29/2012 15:14:15 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER procedure [dbo].[usp_GetTimeReport_Weekly1]
@pi_empId int,
--@pi_v_ep_id int,
--@pi_ep_id int, 
@pi_rptFromDate varchar(10),
@pi_rptToDate varchar(10)
AS
BEGIN
declare @si_sql VARCHAR(1000)

    SET @si_sql = 'SELECT EP_FIRST_NAME + '' '' + EP_LAST_NAME as [Employee_Name],'
    SET @si_sql = @si_sql + 'CONVERT(VARCHAR(3),CONVERT(VARCHAR(3),
                            (SUM(DATEPART(HH,CONVERT (VARCHAR,GTT_NO_OF_HOURS,108))) + (SUM(DATEPART(MI,CONVERT (VARCHAR,GTT_NO_OF_HOURS,108)))/60))))+'':''+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),
                             SUM(DATEPART(MI,CONVERT (VARCHAR,GTT_NO_OF_HOURS,108)))- 60 * (SUM(DATEPART(MI,CONVERT(VARCHAR,GTT_NO_OF_HOURS,108)))/60))+''0'') AS [No_of_Hours] '

    --SET @si_sql = @si_sql + 'CONVERT(VARCHAR(3),CONVERT(VARCHAR(3),
 --                            (SUM(DATEPART(HH,CONVERT (VARCHAR,GTT_NO_OF_HOURS,108))) + (SUM(DATEPART(MI,CONVERT (VARCHAR,GTT_NO_OF_HOURS,108)))/60))))+'':''+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),
 --                             SUM(DATEPART(MI,CONVERT (VARCHAR,GTT_NO_OF_HOURS,108)))- 60 * (SUM(DATEPART(MI,CONVERT(VARCHAR,GTT_NO_OF_HOURS,108)))/60))+''0'') - DATEDIFF(day,v_start_date,v_end_date)* 8 AS [twh] from PGATEINTRA.dbo.EMPLOYEE_VACATIONS '

    SET @si_sql = @si_sql + ' FROM dbo.gitsTimeTracker '
    SET @si_sql = @si_sql + ' inner JOIN dbo.vw_GetUserDetails ON gtt_gu_id = gu_id '
    SET @si_sql = @si_sql + ' inner JOIN PGATEINTRA.dbo.EMPLOYEE_VACATIONS ON V_EP_ID = EP_ID ' 
    SET @si_sql = @si_sql + ' WHERE GTT_WORK_DT BETWEEN ''' + @pi_rptFromDate + ''' AND ''' + @pi_rptToDate + ''' '

    if isnull(@pi_empId, 0) > 0 
        SET @si_sql = @si_sql + ' AND gtt_gu_id = ' + CONVERT(varchar(3), @pi_empId)

    SET @si_sql = @si_sql + ' GROUP BY [EP_FIRST_NAME], [EP_LAST_NAME] '
    print @si_sql
    exec(@si_sql)

    --Record update process ends here
    IF (@@ERROR = 0)
        return @@ERROR
    ELSE
        return 1
END
```

and I got the output from the above procedure is

```
Employee_Name                    No_of_hours
-------------------------------------------
Aditya Sastry A                  96:00
Suresh A                         18:00
Prakash Ajjarapu                 12:40
```

and I wrote one select statement

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day,v_start_date,v_end_date)* 8 AS twh from PGATEINTRA.dbo.EMPLOYEE_VACATIONS
```

and I am getting the output

```
twh
----
56
8
0
8
8
8
0
16
0
16
0
0
8
8
24
0
88
8
0
56
0
0
0
16
0
8
0
0
0
48
0
8
0
0
24
```

the thing is i need to substract No_of_hours from twh and that has to be done in the above procedure and that has to be shown in column as twh

how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Your code is rather unclear and difficult to follow, but a general quick and dirty approach when you need to combine the results of two 'complex' queries is to INSERT them into temp tables and then join the temp tables. This assumes of course that you include some suitable values to join the tables on, in this case it looks like it would be an employee ID of some kind.

In other words, you should aim to be able to write something like this:

```
select
    wh.employee_name,
    wh.working_hours,
    h.holiday_hours,
    wh.working_hours - h.holiday_hours as 'total_hours'
from
    #working_hours wh
    join #holidays h
    on wh.employee_id = h.employee_id
```

I don't think anyone can write the queries for you, because it requires a lot of knowledge about the tables and data, so this is just a general suggestion of one approach that you can take.